# Best way to stop Docker container in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a CI-server (jenkins) which is building new Docker images.
Now I want to run a new Docker container when the build is succesful.
But therefor I have to stop the previous running container.

What's the best way to perform this?
`localhost:5000/test/myapp:"${BUILD_ID}` is the name of my new images. So I'm using the build-id as tag. First I thought to perform:

```
docker stop localhost:5000/dbm/my-php-app:${BUILD_ID-1}
```

But this isn't a right solution because when a build would fail, this would be wrong.

```
Build 1: succes -> run container 1 
Build 2: failed -> run container 1
Build 3: succes -> stop container (3-1) =2 --> wrong (isn't running)
```

What could be a solution? Proposals where I have to change the tag-idea are also welcome

Comment: http://blog.tutum.co/2015/06/08/blue-green-deployment-using-containers/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomasleveil I found the answer on my question:

```
# build the new image
docker build -t localhost:5000/test/myapp:"${BUILD_ID}" .


# remove old container
SUCCESS_BUILD=`wget -qO- http://jenkins_url:8080/job/jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber`

docker rm -f "${SUCCESS_BUILD}" && echo "container ${SUCCESS_BUILD} removed" || echo "container ${SUCCESS_BUILD} does not exist"

# run new container
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name "${BUILD_ID}" localhost:5000/test/myapp:${version}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) command takes a *docker container name* as parameter, not a *docker image ID*.

You would have to name your container when you run it:

```sh
# build the new image
docker build -t localhost:5000/test/myapp:"${BUILD_ID}" .

# remove the existing container
docker rm -f myjob && echo "container myjob removed" || echo "container myjob does not exist"

# create and run a new container
docker run -d --name myjob localhost:5000/test/myapp:"${BUILD_ID}"
```

Just replace `myjob` with a better suited name in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Jenkins Pipeline** and want to gracefully stop and remove containers then here is the solution.

First you have to check is any container is present, and if there is any then you will have to stop and remove it. Here is the code

```js
def doc_containers = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'docker container ps -aq').replaceAll("\n", " ") 
   if (doc_containers) {
        sh "docker stop ${doc_containers}"
    }
```

The variable `doc_containers` will store the container IDs, and you can perform the empty check. If container is not available then `docker stop` command should  not be executed.

Here is the pipeline code

```js
        stage('Clean docker containers'){
            steps{
                script{
                
                    def doc_containers = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'docker container ps -aq').replaceAll("\n", " ") 
                    if (doc_containers) {
                        sh "docker stop ${doc_containers}"
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```